# JMeter: Unable to retrieve Memory Stats

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using JMeter to capture Perf Mon statistics from various servers including CPU, Memory, Disk I/O, Write IOPS, Read IOPS, Packets Rev, and Packets Sent.

It seems like there is a limit on the number of rows that can be specified when trying to collect Memory statistics.

I tried changing the order of the rows specified in the `Servers to Monitor` section and it’s always the first row that causes the `ERROR: java.io.IOException: Agent is unreachable via TCP` messages to appear and the stats for that server to not be captured.  This only happens for Memory for the first server specified.  Capturing stats for CPU, and the other stats for the same server works fine.

Any ideas on how to overcome this error?

Comment: port config in firewall? Have you tried using perfmon  from a different machine to remotely fetch metrics from this server?

Comment: Yes - I was able to us perfmon to fetch metrics.  Seems like there is a limitation in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

I have JMeter test written with 4.0 version with only CPU and memory monitoring. I started the [Perfmon Server Agent](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/) on the application server. For several executions, it collected both the CPU and the memory. Then it started logging the error "Agent is unreachable via TCP" only for the first row, which was CPU in my case.

I stopped the Perfmon Server Agent and then started it again via the startAgent.bat (for Windows). I have not seen the error "Agent is unreachable via TCP" from one week, it seems that the restart has helped.